# Need a better regular expression to match a text

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

My requirement is to find wrong usage patterns of a method callee, for that I want to have a regular expression which can find the invalid usecases.

Ex: I have a method, it will accepts a parameter with predefined formats.

Possible predefined input arguments:

1. abc
2. bbc
3. abc bbc
4. der
5. der abc

Function: **function method(param){}**

Valid function callee use-cases:

1. object.method("abc"); **or** object.method('abc');
2. object.method("bbc"); **or** object.method('bbc');
3. object.method("abc bbc"); **or** object.method('abc bbc');
4. object.method("der"); **or** object.method('der');
5. object.method("der abc"); **or** object.method('der abc');

Invalid use-cases:

1. object.method("abcd");
2. object.method("test");
3. object.method("abc ");
4. object.method("abc bbc ");

In order to identify the invalid use cases I have come with the below regular expression:
Ref: [RegEx] (https://regex101.com/r/fR5eF4/3)

Is it possible to optimize the above regular expression further (or) any other expression with better performance.

Comment: Why are you using regex to begin with?

Comment: @Nit: We are following this way from a log back, I can't change the approach. Hence following it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've came with

```
.(method)\s*\((?![\"\'](abc|bbc|abc bbc|der|der abc)[\"\'])
```

so i've just moved ' and " out of this (x|x|x) group, to make things clearer
also -- you can add /g modifier for testing and put all your data to textbox.
here's link: https://regex101.com/r/oT4nN3/1

Comment: BTW, you can futher improve performance if you remove capturing from `(method)`. Also, I guess you need to match a literal dot, escape it (`\.`). And no need escaping quote symbols inside `[]`. I'd suggest `\.method\s*\((?!["'](abc|bbc|abc bbc|der|der abc)["'])`.

Comment: @stribizhev: I didn't noticed **\.** part, thanks for notifying it and for **[]** part. And coming to capturing '(method)', EOD we need to highlight the wrong-ones rights? (it won't required capturing?)

Comment: @user3620283: With 'method' capturing, the regex is computed in 520, 64, 72, 76 steps. Without, it computes in 390, 48, 56, 60 steps. You do not need to highlight a group, you may highlight the whole match.

Comment: I have small doubt, what is the difference between     <code> \.setDisplayFormat\s*\((?!\s*["'](shortdate|shortdate shorttime|shortdate longtime|longdate|longdate shorttime|longdate longtime|longtime|shorttime)["']) <code> and <code>  \.setDisplayFormat\s*\(\s*(?!["'](shortdate|shortdate shorttime|shortdate longtime|longdate|longdate shorttime|longdate longtime|longtime|shorttime)["']) <code>

Comment: first -- you forgot backslash at first `(` symbol. Instead of `\.setDisplayFormat\s*((?!\s*["'](shortdate|shortdate shorttime|shortdate longtime|longdate|longdate shorttime|longdate longtime|longtime|shorttime)["'])` it should be `\.setDisplayFormat\s*\((?!\s*["'](shortdate|shortdate shorttime|shortdate longtime|longdate|longdate shorttime|longdate longtime|longtime|shorttime)["'])`. And this is the right regex, because second one matches this string (with backslash added) `object.setDisplayFormat ( "shortdate");`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a closed list of valid inputs I would just check that the input coincides with one of them, for example, just by searching an array of options.

If that is not the case you should offer us a better explanation of the required input format.